# Bootstrap Rails 4 sass layout not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I'm using followings:

> Rails 4.1.0
>
> ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]
>
> rvm 1.25.25 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin ,
>   Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass-extras'


# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

and i have done the following tasks to achieve bootstrap-sass-fluid layout through my railsapp :

> bundle install
>
> rails g bootstrap:install
>
> rails g bootstrap:layout application fluid
>
> rails g scaffold Post title:string description:text
>
> rake db:migrate
>
> rails g bootstrap:themed Posts

and i have these files in my assests folder under my rails app :

> /home/pallavsharma/Workspace/testapp/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
>
> /home/pallavsharma/Workspace/testapp/app/assets/stylesheets/posts.css.scss
>
> /home/pallavsharma/Workspace/testapp/app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss

but still i dont have my bootstrap layout in my app

My application.css file contents:

> /*
>
> - This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css,
>     which will include all the files
> - listed below.
>
>   *
> - Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory,
>     lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
> - or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced
>     here using a relative path.
>
>   *
>
> Blockquote
>    * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll
>   appear at the bottom of the
>
> - compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over
>     styles defined in any styles
> - defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is
>     generally better to create a new
> - file per style scope.
>
>   *
>
>   *= require_tree .
>
>   *= require_self
>
>   */

[image]

What else needs to be mentioned please tell.

Comment: Perhaps you should require some files in `application.css` post its content. And rename it to `application.css.scss` with fixing errors:)

Comment: @zishe added application.css file

Comment: add `*= require bootstrap   *= require_tree .    *= require_self`

Comment: adding `*=require bootstrap` worked fine thanks @ziche,
[bootstrap-sass-extras](https://github.com/doabit/bootstrap-sass-extras) they should mention it. anyways thanks :)

Comment: I post it as an answer then.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help. The funny thing - i did the same but it's not working for me=))

Comment: @zishe 1 more thing need to add `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
` gem in gemfile then it worked plz update your answer.

Comment: Thanks, works)) Didn't know about this layout thing, i like this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`application.css.scss` should be:

```
/*
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

Also need to mention this gem in gemfile

```
 gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

and it works.